# element of array doesnt pass into another sub

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have some troubles with arrays.

I have standard module which contains some subs and private variable.
When this module gets called via `userform_initialize` it does some procedures and then it should store array variable and wait until button is clicked to do another procedures..
Problem is that this array variable doesn't hold its elements when I call other procedure.
Simplified example is this:

```
Private exp2() as double 'declaration of module array variable

Private sub1()

//'some code which fills array exp2()

msgbox exp2(x) '- this message box shows correct information stored in variable exp2(x)
sub2
End sub

Private sub2()
Redim preserve exp2(0 to x)
msgbox exp2(x) - this message shows 0
End sub
```

Keep in mind that this is not exactly the flow of my program. Important is to store array variable exp2() for later use.

Comment: You have `x` elements and you are again redimming to `x`? If the two x's are different then `msgbox exp2(x) - this message shows 0` will show `0` because after `Redim preserve exp2(0 to x)`, you have to store the value at `x` position to fetch it's value?

Comment: Jen i dont redim, i get VBA error 9 (subscript i guess). For me it looks like that when calling sub2 procedure, the variable loses its scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Are you trying to achieve something like this ?**

- Here you can access the originally assigned values in the other Sub.

---

```
Private exp2() As Double
Private Sub hh()

ReDim exp2(0 To 1)

    exp2(0) = 1    
    MsgBox exp2(0) ' Prints 1

    hh2

End Sub

Private Sub hh2()
ReDim Preserve exp2(0 To 2)
MsgBox exp2(0) ' also prints 1
End Sub
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what I need. The ONLY diference from my code And yours Is that you use redim preserve in hh1 And I use just redim.

Comment: I think in hh1 you can use Redim also. Won't make a Difference

Comment: @Sniper_of_Chess .. Remove the Preserve from 1st Sub and it will still work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer really depends on what's happening in your "//'some code which fills array exp2()" section. I tested this out as follows and it worked fine:

```
Private exp2() As Double 'declaration of module array variable
Private Sub sub1()
ReDim exp2(1 To 2)
exp2(1) = 2
exp2(2) = 4
MsgBox exp2(2) '- this message box shows correct information stored in variable exp2(x)
sub2
End Sub
Private Sub sub2()
ReDim Preserve exp2(1 To 3)
MsgBox exp2(2)
End Sub
```

So if you're dimensioning the array initial from an index of 1, the redimension would throw an error. But if you're only adding 'rows' to the array beyond what was there initially, it looks like it works. When I tried this, it failed:

```
ReDim Preserve exp2(0 To 2)
MsgBox exp2(2)
```

Comment: Indexing Is correct in my case. What really confuses me Is that first message box shows correct numbers And then next msgbox which Is called right after the first ( but in sub2) shows 0. ( In sub2 before msgbox there Is some variable declarations but nothing in relation with exp2() )

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was really stupid from me. I had double declared array exp2()
One in module level and one in sub1 level. problem solved :)
Thanks all for giving some advices